# gNewSense livecd gives me an Error (callbacks suppressed)

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, kernel-panic

I've a kernel-panic problem (I think) trying to use the liveCD of gNewSense 4.0 for i386.
The error is the following:

```
[8.598401] xhci_queue_intr_tx: 78 callbacks suppressed.
.
.
.
```

It's showing the same error with different codes (70 for example) as long as my laptop is turned on.

I'll give you some information about my hardware:

```
uname -m
x86_64

sudo lshw -short
[sudo] password for lucasdavid: 
H/W path       Device      Class          Description
=====================================================
                           system         Inspiron 14-3467 (078A)
/0                         bus            0PW5P4
/0/0                       memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3d                      memory         6GiB System Memory
/0/3d/0                    memory         4GiB SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/3d/1                    memory         2GiB SODIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/41                      memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/42                      memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/43                      memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/44                      processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
/0/100                     bridge         Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                   display        Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
/0/100/4                   generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                  bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0    usb2        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1    usb1        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/1              input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/1/2              multimedia     USB PnP Sound Device
/0/100/14/1/5              multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/1/6              generic        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/14/1/8              communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14.2                generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/15                  generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/15.1                generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                  communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                  storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c                  bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0    wlp1s0      network        QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.5                bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.5/0  enp2s0      network        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
/0/100/1f                  bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.2                memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4                bus            Intel Corporation
/0/1           scsi0       storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda    disk           1TB ST1000LM035-1RK1
/0/1/0.0.0/1               volume         599MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2   volume         3071MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3   volume         516GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4   /dev/sda4   volume         11GiB Linux swap volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5   /dev/sda5   volume         399GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2           scsi1       storage        
/0/2/0.0.0     /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
/1                         power          DELL 78V9D72
```

I think the problem is with some usb, so more information:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0cf3:e005 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0823 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

That's all!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Any reason why are you using `i386` instead of `amd64`?

Comment: Also, have you tried do blacklist your Realtek card reader module? SdReaders, usb ports and wifi modules of that brand are a bit problematic on Linux - https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/hci_queue_intr_tx-callbacks-suppressed-4175467718/

Comment: You're right. I've downloaded the wrong version.

Comment: Where do I disable them? I'm running Ubuntu in one of my partitions. Do I need to compile the kernel by myself?

Comment: No. You can do it at grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules . If you are using a LiveCD, they usually have syslinux as bootloader, and using the `modprobe.blacklist=name_of_module` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This distribution doesn't have proper drivers for 2 USB and network card that comes with my laptop. I've just installed Trisquel and it works perfectly now!